# Writing and reading at the same time in Python?

Tags: python

I'm a total beginner in Python. I've been trying to shorten the #1 version (which works fine) to a cleaner code and I thought I could just squeeze it into a one-liner. Why doesn't the #2 work?

I'm getting the "NoneType" object has no attribute 'seek' when I try to run it.

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv
  
# 1
open_file = open(filename, 'w+')
open_file.write("Hello world!")
open_file.seek(0)
print open_file.read()

# 2
open_file = open(filename, 'w+').write("Hello world!").seek(0).read()

print open_file
```

I have tried numerous ways but I still can't get it to work.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `open(filename, 'w+').write("Hello world!")` doesn't return file object

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer. Is my #1 the only way I can write the code then? Or is there still a cleaner way? Many thanks :)

Comment: since you're a beginner start learning python 3, not python 2

Comment: #1 is clean enough, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html):

**write(b)**:

- Write the given bytes-like object, b, to the underlying raw stream, and return the number of bytes written

So, it returns the number of bytes written, not a file object, so you cannot chain another call after the `write()`. Note you also cannot chain `seek()` as that returns an offset into the file.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why a one-liner is not working, is because `.write()` does not return back the original file descriptor. Instead, `write()` returns the number of characters/bytes (depending on the opened file mode) that have been written.

Unfortunatelly I don't think there's a way to do what you want in one go, that would not sacrifice readability. What you could do is wrap your code into a function, or write your own file-like object that would immediatelly seek after write.

Answer (score 0):

For writing,

```
with open(filename, 'w+') as f: f.write("Hello world!")
```

and to print content

```
with open(filename, 'r+') as f: print(f.read())
```

works for me! Nonetype error is because of no return type as pointed out by others.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting NoneType because file.write function return None. Or in this case int (How many bytes it has write on the file)

Comment: Hello, thank you. Can i ask you how you would write the code in a cleaner way? Or is my #1 totally fine and not redundant in any way? Thank you!!

Comment: Yes your #1 is totally fine code and you don't need seek as you have only one line in txt file

Answer (score -3):

You must close the file before you open again it. `open_file.close()`